ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED when sending custom client certificate from Electron
I have been trying to send a certificate (in the form of a .pem file) from Electron to my backend (using gevent) and encountering the following error
(node:18946) electron: Failed to load URL: https://127.0.0.1:5050/ with error: ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED 
Front End
const create_cert_principle_issuer = (cert_pem_data) => {
    const cert_pem_obj = pki.certificateFromPem(cert_pem_data)
    const ca_cert_principle_obj = {}
    //maps node-forge certificate key names to electron principle-certificate key names
    const mapping = {
        'countryName': 'country',
        'stateOrProvinceName': 'state',
        'localityName': 'locality',
        'organizationName': 'organizations',
        'organizationalUnitName': 'organizationUnits',
        'commonName': 'commonName'
    }
    for (let key in mapping){
        ca_cert_principle_obj[mapping[key]] = ""
    }
    for (const attribute of cert_pem_obj.issuer.attributes) {
            if (attribute.name in mapping) {
                let new_keyname = mapping[attribute.name]
                ca_cert_principle_obj[new_keyname] = attribute.value
            }
    }
    return ca_cert_principle_obj
}
const create_cert_from_PEM = (cert_pem_data, parent_cert_data) => {
    const is_self_signed = (parent_cert_data === false);
    const subjectPrinciple = create_cert_principle(cert_pem_data)
    const subjectNodeCert = pki.certificateFromPem(cert_pem_data)
    let certDer = forge.pem.decode(cert_pem_data)[0].body
    let md = forge.md.sha1.create()
    md.start()
    md.update(certDer)
    let digest = md.digest()
    let hex = digest.toHex()
    log.info('digest is, ', hex)
    const electron_cert = {
        data: cert_pem_data,
        subject: subjectPrinciple,
        subjectName: subjectPrinciple.commonName,
        serialNumber: subjectNodeCert.serialNumber,
        validStart: subjectNodeCert.validity.notBefore.getTime() / 1000,
        validExpiry: subjectNodeCert.validity.notAfter.getTime() / 1000,
        issuer : create_cert_principle_issuer(cert_pem_data),
        issuerName : subjectNodeCert.issuer.commonName,
        fingerprint: hex
    }
    if(!is_self_signed){
        electron_cert.issuerCert = create_cert_from_PEM(parent_cert_data, false)
    }
    return electron_cert
}

app.on('select-client-certificate', (event, webContents, url, list, send_cert) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const client_cert_data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(certs_path, 'client-auth', 'cert.pem'))
    let cert = create_cert_from_PEM(client_cert_data.toString(), false)
    send_cert([cert])
})

Backend
this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
certfile = os.path.join(this_dir, "certificates", "fullchain.pem")
keyfile = os.path.join(this_dir, "certificates", "privkey.pem")
cafile = os.path.join(this_dir, "certificates", "my-root-ca.crt.pem")
if prod:
    secure_context = SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER, server_side=True)
    secure_context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    secure_context.load_verify_locations(cafile=cafile)
    secure_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)
    http_server = WSGIServer(("127.0.0.1", 5050), app, ssl_context=secure_context)
    http_server.serve_forever()

Essentially on the frontend side, the event listener for 'select-client-certificate' loads in the client certificate pem file, constructs an object according to the shape of the certificate (and its certificate principles), and sends it in lieu of the first item in the known certificate list. The certificate produced appears to be in the same shape as the default certificate that comes with Electron.
The issue, is that upon running this code, it makes it to the send_cert callback and runs it without incident but throws the ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED, as if the certificate is invalid or didnt send.
However, I am fairly sure the certificates are valid because openssl verifies them correctly, and sending the certificates via Axios results in a successful operation.
const agent = new https.Agent({
    ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(certs_path, 'ca', 'my-root-ca.crt.pem')),
    cert:  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(certs_path, 'client-auth', 'cert.pem')),
    key:  fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(certs_path, 'client-auth', 'privkey.pem')),
    servername: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5050,
})
axios.get(url, {httpsAgent: agent})
        .then(res => {
            // load url to see if live
            mainWindow.loadURL(url).then((res)=>{
                console.log("Loaded Successfully")
            })
        })

Any ideas on what may be causing this?
